# Prove that if $\dfrac{ax^2+2bx+c}{\alpha x^2+2\beta x+\gamma} (\alpha\neq 0)$ has $3$ inflection points, then all of them lie on one line?

Tags: calculus

Prove that if the rational function $f(x)=\dfrac{ax^2+2bx+c}{\alpha x^2+2\beta x+\gamma} (\alpha\neq 0)$ has three inflection points, then all of them lie on one line? (All the parameters are real numbers.

It's an exercise problem. And there is a **hint** of this problem:

> Firstly consider the case $a=0, \alpha=1$. Prove that if $b=0$ or $x^2+2\beta x+\gamma=0$ has real roots, then $f(x)$ would not have $3$ inflection points.

Here's my question:

1. I don't know how to prove the case “$x^2+2\beta x+\gamma=0$ has two real roots”.
2. How to prove the general case if we have prove the case $a=0,\alpha=1$?

Comment: If $f''(c)=0$ and $f'''(c)\not=0,$ that is sufficient to show that $c$ is an inflection point. As for your quadratic, use information about the discriminant to see how many roots of what kind you have.

Comment: Try partial fractions if the denominator has real roots.

Comment: Recall that a quadratic equation has 2 real roots iff $\Delta=b^2-4ac>0$. Plug it in and you will get moving.

Comment: @Empy2 I tried this, let $x^2+2\beta x+\gamma=(x-d)(x-e)$, then $\dfrac{2b+c}{(x+d)(x+e)}=2b\dfrac{x+d}{x+e}+\dfrac{c-2bd}{x+d}$, I didnot see anything useful here.

Comment: I don't think you did the partial fraction decomposition correctly, but it does strike me as useful that $g(x)= \frac p{x+q}$ has no points of inflection.

Comment: This question is relevant, though certainly not a duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286541/three-inflection-points-are-on-a-line?rq=1.

Answer (score 1):

For your second question, notice that ...
$$  \begin{align} f(x)&=\dfrac{ax^2+2bx+c}{\alpha x^2+2\beta x+\gamma} 
\\&=\frac a \alpha \Bigg(  1+\dfrac{ \big( \frac ba - \frac \beta\alpha \big)x + \big(  \frac ca - \frac \gamma\alpha   \big) }{   x^2+\frac\beta\alpha x + \frac\gamma\alpha}   \Bigg )
\\
& = \frac a \alpha  \big (1+g(x) \big)   \end{align}$$

where $g(x)$ is a rational function satisfying the requirements of your hint.